Как переделать zip в apk и наоборот?
У меня есть файл apk моего приложения. Долгое время я не смогу получить доступ к android studio, а мне там нужно кое-что подправить. Я знаю, что та папка, к-рая мне нужна, будет так доступна. Но как мне мой apk переделать в zip, а потом обратно собрать?

zip и apk это одно и тоже, термин "преобразовать" здесь не имеет смысла. Только вот после изменения содержимого программы нужно будет переподписать её своим ключом

И как мне это реализовать? Я просто создал приложение в android studio и ничего не подписывал. И кстати, Вы предлагаете установить zip файл на телефон в качестве приложения?)))

Подкорректировал вопрос.

@Vova apk расширение это буквально такое же расширение, что и zip. И да, вы можете открыть zip файл через пакетный установщик на некоторых девайсах, и да, это сработает.
